running LEDs off 12 V
I’m trying to run my 12 V adapter to 19 12 V LEDs 10 mm with
14 3.2 V 20 mA LEDs. I’ve used resistors (Carbon firm 1/4 W 5% 1 Kohm) on each LED.
Problem:
I can’t get the 14 3.2 V to light up.
But the 19 12 V all light up.
Sorry no schematic. I only have a touchscreen phone. Not compatible with the editor.
I strung all the 3.2 V together one after the other with the 12 V 10 mm LEDs in bundles
One at the 10th 3.2 V LED and then again at the very end of the string.

Welcome. You've given us no idea how you hooked these up or what LEDs and resistors you used. Please add a schematic and any information you have on the LEDs to your question, not in the comments. There is a schematic editor in the question editor, it's not hard to use.

Sorry I’ll try and elaborate better

Resolve:? is not even a question ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

"I strung all the 3.2 v together one after another" leads to 3.2V x 14 = 44.8V ... so how would that work off a 12V supply?

Still not clear. If you have the 3.2V LEDs all in series it's not going to work. A 12V LED is typically a regular LED with a built-in resistor. You would need to have all of those in parallel across the supply. Then you would have to add a resistor to each 3.2V LED and then put each LED/resistor pair in parallel across the supply as you did with the 12V LEDs. Is this what you did, or do you have them in series with each other? I suspect that you have the 12V ones in parallel and the 3.2V ones in series.

That would be correct a string of 3.2v and parallel 12v so if I bundled the 3.2 to parallel it would work ?

Burhans I did think about that but didn’t know it would affect the outcome. What would I need to increase the value to adapter wise?

The all-too-common way to use 3.odd V LEDs with a 12 V supply is to put three in series with a resistor to limit the current. Consult the datasheets for an idea about lifetime.

Thank you godjhyo ,greybeard1

Sketch a schematic on a piece of paper, take a photo, and post it.

The individual '12V' LEDs have built-in dropping resistors. They can be wired directly to 12V in parallel. Don’t wire them in series. Otherwise, there's no issue with them.
With your 3.2V LEDs, you will want to break them up into groups of three, then wire them in series with a 120 ohm resistor to set current at 20mA for the string.
Why? A set of 3 LEDs has a combined forward drop of 9.6V, leaving 2.4V to be dropped in the resistor. We have enough voltage left over to make current limiting work: we get R = (12-9.6V)/20mA = 120 ohms.
With four or more LEDs in a row, their combined forward voltage exceeds 12V (that is, 12.8V), which won't work. Practically no current will flow.
For the last two LEDs left over (you said you had 14). Their combined drop is 6.4V, leaving 5.6V to be shed in the resistor. Same math: we get (12-6.4V)/20mA = 280 ohms.
Arranged like so (simulate it here):

